# Deriving bearing in degrees minutes seconds format from field calculator

Tags: qgis

I'd like to know if there's a formula for calculating bearings of lines in degrees minutes seconds format. I already have been able to get the bearings in decimal degrees using:

```
CONCAT(format_number(degrees(azimuth(start_point($geometry), end_point($geometry))), 2), '°')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to use an intermediate field containing the bearings in decimal degrees, I suggest not adding the '°' sign, but create a field "DEGREES" of type 'real' and populate it like this:

```
degrees(azimuth(start_point($geometry), end_point($geometry)))
```

Then, by using this field calculator expression in a new text field, you can format your angle in degrees, minutes, seconds:

```
concat(floor("DEGREES"), '° ', floor("DEGREES"*60 % 60), ''' ', "DEGREES"*3600 % 60, '''')
```

Or you could also do it with a single expression from the geometry directly:

```
concat(floor(degrees(azimuth(start_point($geometry), end_point($geometry)))), '° ', 
floor(degrees(azimuth(start_point($geometry), end_point($geometry)))*60 % 60), ''' ', 
degrees(azimuth(start_point($geometry), end_point($geometry)))*3600 % 60, '''')
```

Comment: Thank you @FSimardGIS, I've successfully derived the bearing in dms in the field calculator with your expression. Worked like magic